# Tem como programar em java criando frame pelo VS code?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, visual-studio-code, jframe

Estou aprendendo java swing e queria saber se tem como fazer uma JFrame e executar pelo vs code, pois quero começar a usar apenaas uma ide pra tudo e o netbeans demora demais para iniciar, e como configurar isso? desde ja agradeço.

Comment: Por que você não usa o Notepad++ e executa o código por linha de comando?

Comment: Não acho o "*melhor editor de códigos do mundo*", mas o [netbeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb123/nb123.html) serve bem ao propósito. E depois de alguns anos usando, eu percebi que a Oracle deu uma boa melhorada no desempenho da UI. Recomendo isso também...

Answer (score 4):

Sim é possível, um JFrame nada mais é que um código Java qualquer.

Para rodar códigos Java no Visual Studio Code você deve instalar [este plugin](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java).

Acredito não ser produtivo, pelo fato de você ter de escrever manualmente o código de suas telas, visto que o Visual Studio Code **não possui um UI Editor**, como o plugin [WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) do Eclipse.